# accept multiple values from user

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I am developing `dash` application. I want to provide functionality that accepts `multiple` values (preferably comma separated) from the user.

Currently trying, by having an `input` box with `type=text` and user enters values by manually typing `comma` like below in the code, and in the callback I am getting it as `str` which I need to convert into `list` as final result which will be further used in computation.

```
# Input in textbox
-1, "", "na", "#99", 100

# Received in callback
val='-1, "", "na", "#99", 100'

# Output
[-1, "", "na", "#99", 100]
```

```
import dash
from dash import Dash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

dbc_css = (
    "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/AnnMarieW/dash-bootstrap-templates@V1.0.2/dbc.min.css"
)

app = Dash(
    __name__,
    suppress_callback_exceptions=True,
    external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP, dbc_css],
)


btn1 = dbc.Button(id='btn1', children='click')
ip1 = dbc.Input(id='ip1', type='text')
div1 = html.Div(id='div1')

@app.callback(
    Output('div1', 'children'),
    Input('btn1', 'n_clicks'),
    State('ip1', 'value'),
    prevent_initial_call=True,
)
def get_values_and_process(n, val):
    status = False
    
    if n is None:
        raise PreventUpdate
    
    print(f"{val=}")
    print(f"{type(val)}") 
    
    # proposed(trying to do this way)
    # get the input value which is string and convert into list and then use it further   

    return status

app.layout = dbc.Container(html.Div([btn1, ip1, div1]))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port="8001", debug=True)
```

I tried searching for a built-in component in dash for this functionality but no success. Is there any better way to achieve this by avoiding user not to type comma like such?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you just need to turn a string into a list. The split method is probably the best for this considering you already have commas separating your values.

val='-1, "", "na", "#99", 100'

val = val.split(",")

This will turn your string into a list.

Comment: Hi Nate, Thanks. With the above flow, this will be next step. But I am searching more for avoiding user manually type comma.